# Variance of time to transition to next state in Markov chain.

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I have a very simple three state Markov chain. We have that $s_1 \to s_2  \to s_3 \to s_1$.
The probability of transition is $p$ and the probability of staying in the same state is, therefore, $1-p$.

The average transition time to next is given by $1/p$.

My question is: What is the variance of the transition time?

Comment: The distribution of the transition time is geometric, and so..

Comment: @Math1000  That's easy now  $\frac{1-p}{p^2}$.  How do we show that the distribution is geometric? Is it easy to do? If not a reference would be great.

Comment: It's pretty clear from inspection - considering a transition to a new state as a "success" and remaining in the same state as a "failure," the geometric distribution should immediately pop into mind.